# Unity UI Strange Behaviour

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 2d scene with a camera set to the default distance of -100. If I add a canvas it for some reason has a default plane distance of 100 (not sure why as surely this would place it behind the scene?) and set to Screen-Space Camera.

The oddness happens when I add UI elements. For instance if I add a button, I first have to set its z position to at least -65 (Again I have no idea why) or it does not show in the editor. But if I run the game the Text does not show. Now if I delete the button element and instead first add another element (can be anything but lets just say it is a text element) then I add a button element. They are both not visible until I set one of their z positions to -65 or greater. Now that is strange enough but now if I run the game the element which is set to -65 is not visible but the one set to z position 0 is showing correctly...... now if I swap their z positions and run the game the one that was visible is now hidden and the other is now visible.......

What on earth is going on?

Note if I set the canvas to screen space overlay everything works fine without any messing about but the canvas looks tiny in the editor and is about 1/8th the size of the scene while being off centre and not resizeable or re-positionable..... When the game runs it is fine though and fills the screen (again I have not idea why this is).

Note my camera is set to a size of 540 in order to lock it to 1080p

Comment: The choice between Screen Space Camera and Screen Space Overlay should really be - do you ever want any of the UI elements to go behind the 3D geometry? (I completely agree the giant/tiny UI in the editor on Overlay is annoying mind you..)

Comment: So the choice is between a canvas that acts quirky or one that I can't arrange the elements properly in the designer? Surely this is a major oversight?

Comment: With screen space camera, I have noticed that Text elements don't render when "Maximize on Play" is checked, even in the latest 5.2. Does the behavior you see happen even in a new scene with just the Main Camera and a Canvas?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why your text isn't showing but whenever I've had trouble with `screen space camera` it's ended up being that the text was miles away and hence behind something, or too close and being clipped out. If you don't want the text to actually be in the 3d space of your scene, or applied to a second camera, you almost certainly want screen space overlay. In terms of the editor I'd have preferred the overlay version to just appear overlaid when selected and hide the rest of the time, rather than floating about either huge or tiny - but it's more an annoyance than a problem surely?

Comment: No it is a major problem as I want to set the ui elements like timers and lives remaining to be in a particular place so as to not be in the way etc. The fact that the canvas shows so small in relation to my scene means that I have no idea where everything will be until I play the game... it is only a single screen 2d game so I would expect to be able to set the canvas to the size of my scene.....

Comment: I forgot to mention that my camera is set to size 540. I have updated the post